# Why isn't there visual inheritance in WPF?

Tags: wpf, inheritance

In Windows Forms, it was useful at times to have one window that inherited from another window. But in WPF, this is not allowed. Why is there no visual inheritance for WPF windows?

Comment: As a WinForms developer for several years, I've not once seen the use of a window inheriting from another window. I'm curious to know what's the use case for that.

Comment: @Judah: I always use it to build a base (template) dialogbox for example. Maybe you should give it a try once.

Comment: @Judah: I've used it time and again with user controls... You use it when you want a basic UI to be augmented in different ways...

Comment: Form inheritance in WinForms was OK for simple things, but completely useless for anything more complex. Especially if 3rd party components were involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, a large effort was made to separate visual from logical.  Because of this, there is a LARGE amount of freedom to make the UI look however you want.  All of the controls, including windows, are "lookless".  You can provide your own look via templates and styles.  A default visual style has been provided that makes everything look like you would expect, but you don't have to use it.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: I agree. This answer is factually accurate and informative but entirely irrelevant to the question of why WPF doesn't have any sort of visual inheritance mechanism.

Comment: it has everything to do with the question. what is he saying that the **sort of** visual inheritance in the question is thwarted by flexibility of WPF and there are different ways to do what is asked, therefore visual inheritance is there but not in the way the OP wanted

Answer (score 7):

The reason WPF does not support visual inheritance is due to the fact that the form design is achieved via markup (.xaml) as opposed to winforms which use code-behind to produce the layout.  Code-behind is extensible and markup is not.  The same goes for web forms.  Master pages in asp.net offer a quasi visual inheritance.  So it is a trade off, markup offers the benefit of a clear separation of layout and data whereas code-behind offer visual extensibility.  It is a bit of a shame since visual extensibility works so well in creating consistency in the GUI as well as very rapid development.  Well, it seems flare is more in demand than functionality.  WPF is just ok...

Answer (score 2):

WPF is deliberately very, very different from Windows Forms. The composability model is not based on Windows, but on classes like [Dependency Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx), [Visual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.aspx), [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx). You can also dramatically modify the behavior of existing things using control templates, styles, data binding and other techniques.

I encourage you to experiment!  WPF is very easy to prototype with