# Inherit from a WPF window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, inheritance

I've a windows that should be the same between 2 applications, except some points.
I wanted to inherit from it to create a subclass(which has no XAML), that only does some customization(like window's title) in the constructor.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried? ;)

Comment: Why not common style?

Comment: [Why isn't there visual inheritance in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714283/why-isnt-there-visual-inheritance-in-wpf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# - inheritance WPF layout - Window from Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454202/c-sharp-inheritance-wpf-layout-window-from-window)

Answer (score 5):

> Is this possible?

Yes.

Create a class that inherits from `System.Windows.Window`:

```
public class YourBaseClass : Window
{
    public YourBaseClass() : base()
    {
        Title = "Common Title";
    }
}
```

...and change the base class of your windows to use this one, both in the code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : YourBaseClass
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

...and in XAML:

```
<local:YourBaseClass x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="300" Width="300">
</local:YourBaseClass>
```

Comment: Do you know if this works for WinUI 3? I'm struggling to get the inheritance to work.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike window forms, WPF have no visual inheritance. You may refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714283/why-isnt-there-visual-inheritance-in-wpf/) for why.

Therefore, we cannot use inheritance here. However, you can  add custom property to your windows class and made the customization based on the property.

Let say I want to create two similar windows with different "Title" ( this is just an example, i do know window has a Title property):

in xaml.cs:

```
public WindowTest //constructor 
{
   InitializeComponent(); 
   this.Loaded+=WindowTest_Loaded; 
}

private void WindowTest_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Please note that custom property wont be set until Windows is loaded.
    //Your customization here
    this.Title = TitleText; 
}

public string TitleText
{
    get { return GetValue( Property1Property ).ToString(); }
    set { SetValue( TitleTextProperty, value ); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Property1.  
// This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleTextProperty 
    = DependencyProperty.Register( 
      "TitleText", 
      typeof( string ), 
      typeof( WindowTest ), 
      new PropertyMetadata( String.Empty ) 
  );
```

in xaml

```
<Grid>
    <test:WindowText TitleText = "Hello World"/>  //first window
    <test:WindowText TitleText = "I Hate You"/>  //second window
</Grid>
```